CPU Usage not updating
I’ve written SwiftUI code that uses Combine to display CPU usage metrics such as User, System, Nice, and Idle values for each core on the system. The functionality works initially in the sense that when the app launches, the usage data is correctly fetched and displayed.
However, I’ve encountered a problem: after the initial data is displayed, the values do not update in real-time as I expected. The Combine publisher seems to stop triggering updates after the first fetch, and no new data is reflected in the UI.
I'm looking for guidance on how to make the values refresh continuously or at regular intervals. Perhaps I'm missing something in the way Combine is set up, or maybe there's a more effective approach for keeping the UI updated with real-time data.
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Here's my code:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var cpuMonitor = CPUUsageMonitor()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Overall CPU Usage")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()

                ForEach(0..<cpuMonitor.cpuUsages.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Core \(index):")
                            .font(.headline)

                        HStack {
                            Text("User: ")
                            Text("\(cpuMonitor.cpuUsages[index].user, specifier: "%.2f")%")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("System: ")
                            Text("\(cpuMonitor.cpuUsages[index].system, specifier: "%.2f")%")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Nice: ")
                            Text("\(cpuMonitor.cpuUsages[index].nice, specifier: "%.2f")%")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Idle: ")
                            Text("\(cpuMonitor.cpuUsages[index].idle, specifier: "%.2f")%")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            cpuMonitor.startMonitoring()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            cpuMonitor.stopMonitoring()
        }
    }
}

class CPUUsageMonitor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cpuUsages: [CoreUsage] = []

    private var cpuInfo: processor_info_array_t!
    private var prevCpuInfo: processor_info_array_t?
    private var numCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    private var numPrevCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    private var numCPUs: uint = 0
    private var timerCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        let mibKeys: [Int32] = [CTL_HW, HW_NCPU]
        mibKeys.withUnsafeBufferPointer { mib in
            var sizeOfNumCPUs: size_t = MemoryLayout<uint>.size
            let status = sysctl(processor_info_array_t(mutating: mib.baseAddress), 2, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, nil, 0)
            if status != 0 {
                numCPUs = 1
            }
        }
        cpuUsages = Array(repeating: CoreUsage(user: 0.0, system: 0.0, nice: 0.0, idle: 0.0), count: Int(numCPUs))
    }

    func startMonitoring() {
        timerCancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.updateInfo()
            }
    }

    func stopMonitoring() {
        timerCancellable?.cancel()
    }

    func updateInfo() {
        var numCPUsU: natural_t = 0
        var cpuLoadInfo: processor_info_array_t!
        var cpuLoadInfoCount: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
        let err: kern_return_t = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuLoadInfo, &cpuLoadInfoCount)
        
        if err == KERN_SUCCESS {
            var updatedUsages: [CoreUsage] = []

            for i in 0..<Int32(numCPUs) {
                let userTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                let systemTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                let niceTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                let idleTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]

                let total = userTicks + systemTicks + niceTicks + idleTicks
                let userUsage = Float(userTicks) / Float(total) * 100
                let systemUsage = Float(systemTicks) / Float(total) * 100
                let niceUsage = Float(niceTicks) / Float(total) * 100
                let idleUsage = Float(idleTicks) / Float(total) * 100

                let coreUsage = CoreUsage(user: userUsage, system: systemUsage, nice: niceUsage, idle: idleUsage)
                updatedUsages.append(coreUsage)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cpuUsages = updatedUsages
            }

            // Deallocate previous CPU info
            if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
                let prevCpuInfoSize: size_t = MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride * Int(numPrevCpuInfo)
                vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, vm_address_t(bitPattern: prevCpuInfo), vm_size_t(prevCpuInfoSize))
            }

            // Store the current info for future deallocation
            prevCpuInfo = cpuLoadInfo
            numPrevCpuInfo = cpuLoadInfoCount
        } else {
            print("Error gathering CPU info!")
        }
    }
}

struct CoreUsage {
    var user: Float
    var system: Float
    var nice: Float
    var idle: Float
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


The @Published property is not updated, right? What about the timer? Is it called every second? And what about updateInfo(), does it assign new values to cpuUsages?

Yes, I am pretty sure that it does

I ran this in Xcode and values in updatedUsages are changing very little, which I find suspicious.

@KarlEhrlich Your problem is not with the SwiftUI view updates, as you can see with a simple let _ = Self._printChanges() in the view's body. I.e. your view does update with every change of cpuUsages. In my tests, updateInfo also regularly returned new values, so the error must lie somewhere in the retrieval or processing of the processor info values if you are not getting the results you're expecting to get.

Your calculation of the ticks is incorrect, that's why you're getting wrong values. You have to factor in the prevCpuInfo properly:
if let prevCpuInfo {
    for i in 0..<Int32(numCPUs) {
        let userTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)] - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
        let systemTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)] - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
        let niceTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)] - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
        let idleTicks = cpuLoadInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)] - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]

        let total = userTicks + systemTicks + niceTicks + idleTicks
        let userUsage = Float(userTicks) / Float(total) * 100
        let systemUsage = Float(systemTicks) / Float(total) * 100
        let niceUsage = Float(niceTicks) / Float(total) * 100
        let idleUsage = Float(idleTicks) / Float(total) * 100

        let coreUsage = CoreUsage(user: userUsage, system: systemUsage, nice: niceUsage, idle: idleUsage)
        updatedUsages.append(coreUsage)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cpuUsages = updatedUsages
    }
}


The Combine publisher seems to stop triggering updates after the first fetch, and no new data is reflected in the UI.

I could not reproduce this and your code does not seem to have any errors in this regard.
